# Usage of GetDlgItemText() in win32 apps

Tags: c, winapi

Can anybody illustrate the usage of `GetDlgItemText()` in **`win32`** apps?

```
char msg [DEFAULT_MSGLEN];    
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_REPLYBOX, (LPSTR)&msg, DEFAULT_MSGLEN);
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_CHATSCREEN, TEXT(strcat( "YOU : ", msg ));
```

Comment: Um, you just did.

Comment: @Raymond: I doubt that this illustrates *correct* usage. The cast is an error, and I stopped counting the errors in the expression `TEXT(strcat( "YOU : ", msg ))` alone. The missing closing `)` is probably the least serious error.

Comment: @IInspectable Those are errors in `SetDlgItemText`. The cast in the `GetDlgItemText` is unnecessary but not an error.

Comment: @Raymond: Well, I can't argue that. You are right on both accounts. There's still an error, though: You cannot use a `char` array unless you explicitly call the ANSI version (`GetDlgItemTextA`). `GetDlgItemText` requires the use of a `TCHAR` array (which, by coincidence, sometimes really is a `char` array).

Answer (score 1):

1. If your project is Unicode, you have to define `msg` as `TCHAR` not `char`.
2. `strcat( "YOU : ", msg )` is serious bug. Allocate buffer variable e.g. `TCHAR buf[256]`, then `wsprintf( buf, TEXT( "YOU : %s" ), msg )`.

Comment: While you comments are good and valid, they do not answer the original question, as you do not use `GetDlgItemText/GetDlgItemText`.

Comment: I am not sure whether the question is "What is my error" or "Please explain what this example does". Anyway, the example cannot be compiled and cannot work.

Comment: it is a win32 app and i need to display this on a window. So i dnt think wsprintf will do the job.

Comment: `wsprintf` "prints" in a string. It is Win32 API equivalent to `sprintf` but supports Unicode. You can do the same with `lstrcpy( buf, TEXT( "YOU : " ) ); lstrcat( buf, msg );`, but with `wsprintf` it is shorter. In your original posting `strcat` adds string to memory which is not free and may clear other data.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDlgItemText()` is use to retrieves the title or text associated with a control in a dialog box.

```
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_REPLYBOX, (LPSTR)&msg, DEFAULT_MSGLEN);
```

this code is getting the text of your `IDC_REPLYBOX`

```
CString s;
s.Format("YOU: %s",msg);
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_CHATSCREEN, s);
```

And this one is setting the new text for the `IDC_CHATSCREEN`

try to save your text into variable first so that, you will not concat it inside the SetDlgItem

Comment: Ask your self why you used that cast, and what the `TEXT()` macro does

Comment: TEXT ("YOU : %s", msg) is not working
It prints YOU : %s itself

Comment: I updated my answer..sorry about that, try my new answer instead

Comment: The question was tagged with the C language

Comment: i think he mean vc++ here, cause i am using that code in vc++6.0

Comment: No, C means C. And Windows API means Windows API. There is no `CString` in C or the Windows API. Plus, using Visual C++ 6 as a reference compiler in 2015 is a capital crime.